# Hive query on a phoenix table throws ColumnNotFoundException

Tags: hadoop, hive, emr, amazon-emr, apache-phoenix

I run an EMR cluster with hbase and hive (hive-server2).

1. My ETL pipeline creates and populates a Phoenix table with data.

   ```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS UNMAPPED_FACTS (
     ACCOUNT VARCHAR NOT NULL,
     CONTAINER VARCHAR NOT NULL,
     UID_TYPE VARCHAR NOT NULL,
     UID VARCHAR NOT NULL,
     TS_EPOCH_MILLIS BIGINT NOT NULL,
     DP_KEY VARCHAR NOT NULL,
     DP_VALUE VARCHAR NOT NULL
       CONSTRAINT pk PRIMARY KEY (ACCOUNT, CONTAINER, UID_TYPE, UID, TS_EPOCH_MILLIS, DP_KEY)
   ) SALT_BUCKETS = 256
   ```
2. Then I create an `EXTERNAL` table in hive metastore pointing to my phoenix table.

   ```
   CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS unmapped_facts (
       account STRING,
       container STRING,
       uid_type STRING,
       uid STRING,
       ts_epoch_millis BIGINT,
       dp_key STRING,
       dp_value STRING
   )
   STORED BY 'org.apache.phoenix.hive.PhoenixStorageHandler'
   TBLPROPERTIES (
   "phoenix.table.name" = "UNMAPPED_FACTS",
   "phoenix.zookeeper.quorum" = "${zookeeper_host}",
   "phoenix.zookeeper.znode.parent" = "/hbase",
   "phoenix.zookeeper.client.port" = "2181",
   "phoenix.rowkeys" = "ACCOUNT, CONTAINER, UID_TYPE, UID, TS_EPOCH_MILLIS, DP_KEY"
   );
   ```
3. Then I run `hive` queries on it, for example:

   ```
   select * from unmapped_facts limit 10
   ```

All of that worked when I used `EMR 5.6.0` (`Phoenix 4.9.0-HBase-1.2` and `HBase 1.2.3`).

Now I upgraded EMR to the latest `5.7.0`  (`Phoenix 4.11.0-HBase-1.3` and `HBase 1.3.1`) and now steps 1 and 2 work fine, but executing the query throws an exception (see below). I can execute sql queries on my phoenix tables using `sqlline` without any problem.

Any help with debugging the problem would be very appreciated.

```
Caused by: org.apache.phoenix.schema.ColumnNotFoundException: ERROR 504 (42703): Undefined column. columnName=UNMAPPED_FACTS.account
        at org.apache.phoenix.schema.PTableImpl.getColumnForColumnName(PTableImpl.java:818) ~[phoenix-4.11.0-HBase-1.3-hive.jar:?]
        at org.apache.phoenix.compile.FromCompiler$SingleTableColumnResolver.resolveColumn(FromCompiler.java:478) ~[phoenix-4.11.0-HBase-1.3-hive.jar:?]
        at org.apache.phoenix.compile.TupleProjectionCompiler$ColumnRefVisitor.visit(TupleProjectionCompiler.java:208) ~[phoenix-4.11.0-HBase-1.3-hive.jar:?]
        at org.apache.phoenix.compile.TupleProjectionCompiler$ColumnRefVisitor.visit(TupleProjectionCompiler.java:194) ~[phoenix-4.11.0-HBase-1.3-hive.jar:?]
        at org.apache.phoenix.parse.ColumnParseNode.accept(ColumnParseNode.java:56) ~[phoenix-4.11.0-HBase-1.3-hive.jar:?]
        at org.apache.phoenix.compile.TupleProjectionCompiler.createProjectedTable(TupleProjectionCompiler.java:109) ~[phoenix-4.11.0-HBase-1.3-hive.jar:?]
        at org.apache.phoenix.compile.QueryCompiler.compileSingleFlatQuery(QueryCompiler.java:528) ~[phoenix-4.11.0-HBase-1.3-hive.jar:?]
        at org.apache.phoenix.compile.QueryCompiler.compileSingleQuery(QueryCompiler.java:507) ~[phoenix-4.11.0-HBase-1.3-hive.jar:?]
        at org.apache.phoenix.compile.QueryCompiler.compileSelect(QueryCompiler.java:202) ~[phoenix-4.11.0-HBase-1.3-hive.jar:?]
        at org.apache.phoenix.compile.QueryCompiler.compile(QueryCompiler.java:157) ~[phoenix-4.11.0-HBase-1.3-hive.jar:?]
        at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$ExecutableSelectStatement.compilePlan(PhoenixStatement.java:475) ~[phoenix-4.11.0-HBase-1.3-hive.jar:?]
        at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$ExecutableSelectStatement.compilePlan(PhoenixStatement.java:441) ~[phoenix-4.11.0-HBase-1.3-hive.jar:?]
        at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.compileQuery(PhoenixStatement.java:1648) ~[phoenix-4.11.0-HBase-1.3-hive.jar:?]
        at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.compileQuery(PhoenixStatement.java:1641) ~[phoenix-4.11.0-HBase-1.3-hive.jar:?]
        at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.optimizeQuery(PhoenixStatement.java:1635) ~[phoenix-4.11.0-HBase-1.3-hive.jar:?]
        at org.apache.phoenix.hive.mapreduce.PhoenixInputFormat.getQueryPlan(PhoenixInputFormat.java:260) ~[phoenix-4.11.0-HBase-1.3-hive.jar:?]
        at org.apache.phoenix.hive.mapreduce.PhoenixInputFormat.getSplits(PhoenixInputFormat.java:131) ~[phoenix-4.11.0-HBase-1.3-hive.jar:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.getNextSplits(FetchOperator.java:372) ~[hive-exec-2.1.1-amzn-0.jar:2.1.1-amzn-0]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.getRecordReader(FetchOperator.java:304) ~[hive-exec-2.1.1-amzn-0.jar:2.1.1-amzn-0]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.getNextRow(FetchOperator.java:459) ~[hive-exec-2.1.1-amzn-0.jar:2.1.1-amzn-0]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.pushRow(FetchOperator.java:428) ~[hive-exec-2.1.1-amzn-0.jar:2.1.1-amzn-0]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchTask.fetch(FetchTask.java:146) ~[hive-exec-2.1.1-amzn-0.jar:2.1.1-amzn-0]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.getResults(Driver.java:2098) ~[hive-exec-2.1.1-amzn-0.jar:2.1.1-amzn-0]
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.getNextRowSet(SQLOperation.java:479) ~[hive-service-2.1.1-amzn-0.jar:2.1.1-amzn-0]
        ... 25 more
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved it looking at this link: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/external-table-creation-in-hive-linking-apache-phoenix/td-p/189307

You just had to add a property "phoenix.column.mapping" and then map each hive table column to a phoenix table column, BUT each left column in the mapping MUST BE lowercase.

Worked like a charm.